# How can I use JQuery to change a CListViews dataProvider?

Tags: jquery, listview, yii

I have the following code, and when a button is clicked i would like to change the dataProvider... how can i do this with JQuery?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$inboxMessages,
            'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}", 
            'itemView'=>'_messageView',
            'id'=>'listMessages',
        ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the yiiListView.update js helper function to do what you want. You would just need to put a conditional before you create the widget to determine the data provider, e.g.:

```
$dp = ($_GET['type'] == 'sent') ? $sentMessages : $inboxMessages;
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dp,
    ...
```

Then create a button with a click event like:

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update('listMessages',
{data:'type=sent', url:'/messages?sort=timestamp&ajax=listMessages'});
```

You can look [here](http://code.google.com/p/zii/source/browse/trunk/widgets/assets/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js?r=96) for more info or search for yiilistview.js examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wish to think it is possible. However, the data provider is assigned (and processed) in server-side. If you want to change the data provider using jquery, it looks like you'll need to load all the CListView again asynchronously

Comment: Well that is quite more complicated that what i hoped for! Maybe it would be a better idea to have simply two CListViews, what do you think?

Comment: It's not that hard. All you need to do is to detect a click on that button, and call `$.ajax({options...});` from jQuery. One of the options is `success`, which lets you do something with the returning web. If you look for renderPartial, you'll find the other half of the solution. Anyway, having two listviews and alternating them between display:block and display:none is easier, yes.